# How to reverse a 2-dimensional table (DataFrame) into a 1 dimensional list?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I am looking in Python/Pandas for a tip that reverses a 2-dimension table into 1 dimensional list.

I usually leverage an Excel function to do it, but I believe that there is a smart Python way to do it.

**Step**

[image: The steps of "2-dimension table into 1 dimension list"]

More details of the Excel way:
http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2461-excel-reverse-pivot-table.html

Comment: do you have a sample input / sample output in Python?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

This type of operation could also be done using [`pd.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html), which unpivots a DataFrame.

If the DataFrame `df` looks like this:

```
  row labels  Tue  Wed  Thu  Sat  Sun  Fri  Mon
0      Apple   21   39   24   27   37   46   42
1     Banana   32   50   48   35   21   27   22
2       Pear   37   20   45   45   31   50   32
```

Then we select the `row_labels` column to be our `id_var` and the rest of the columns to be our values (`value_vars`). We can even choose the new names for the columns at the same time:

```
>>> pd.melt(df, 
            id_vars='row labels', 
            value_vars=list(df.columns[1:]), # list of days of the week
            var_name='Column', 
            value_name='Sum of Value')

   row labels   Column   Sum of Value
0       Apple      Tue             21
1      Banana      Tue             32
2        Pear      Tue             37
3       Apple      Wed             39
4      Banana      Wed             50
5        Pear      Wed             20
...
```

The `value_vars` are stacked below each other: if the column values need to be in a particular order it will be necessary to sort the columns after melting.

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick:

```
table = [
            ["Lables", "A", "B", "C"],
            ["X", 1, 2, 3],
            ["Y", 4, 5, 6],
            ["Z", 7, 8, 9]
        ]

new_table = [["Row", "Column", "Data"]]
for line in table[1:]:
    for name, cell in zip(table[0], line)[1:]:       # py2
#   for name, cell in list(zip(table[0], line))[1:]: # py3
    
        new_line = [line[0], name, cell]
        new_table.append(new_line)
print(new_table)
```

The output is:

```
[
    ['Row', 'Column', 'Data'],
    ['X', 'A', 1],
    ['X', 'B', 2],
    ['X', 'C', 3],
    ['Y', 'A', 4],
    ['Y', 'B', 5],
    ['Y', 'C', 6],
    ['Z', 'A', 7],
    ['Z', 'B', 8],
    ['Z', 'C', 9]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Example taken from http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html

tl;dr, use:

```
from pandas import *
df.stack()
```

====================

Let's give an example of how this can be done.

Generate the sample data first:

```
from pandas import *
import pandas.util.testing as tm; tm.N = 3
import numpy as np
def unpivot(frame):
    N, K = frame.shape
    data = {'value' : frame.values.ravel('F'),
            'variable' : np.asarray(frame.columns).repeat(N),
            'date' : np.tile(np.asarray(frame.index), K)}
    return DataFrame(data, columns=['date', 'variable', 'value'])
df = unpivot(tm.makeTimeDataFrame())
df2=  df.pivot('date', 'variable')
```

We will unpivot this table:

```
               value                              
variable           A         B         C         D
date                                              
2000-01-03 -0.425081  0.163899 -0.216486 -0.266285
2000-01-04  0.078073  0.581277  0.103257 -0.338083
2000-01-05  0.721696 -1.311509 -0.379956  0.642527
```

Run:

```
df2=  df.pivot('date', 'variable')
print df2
```

Voila! Now we get the desired table.

```
                        value
date       variable          
2000-01-03 A        -0.425081
           B         0.163899
           C        -0.216486
           D        -0.266285
2000-01-04 A         0.078073
           B         0.581277
           C         0.103257
           D        -0.338083
2000-01-05 A         0.721696
           B        -1.311509
           C        -0.379956
           D         0.642527
```