# Change columns to rows per student ID

Tags: excel, pandas, dataframe, pandas-melt, pandas-merge

I have data in excel sheet that I am reading into a dataframe:

| ID | Grade | Course | Q1 Number | Q1 Letter | Q2 Number | Q2 Letter |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 9 | English | 73 | B | 69 | C |
| 1 | 9 | Math | 70 | B | 52 | C |
| 1 | 9 | Science | 69 | C | 80 | A |

desired output:

| ID | Grade | Course | Semester | Number Grade | Letter Grade |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 9 | English | Q1 | 73 | B |
| 1 | 9 | English | Q2 | 69 | C |
| 1 | 9 | Math | Q1 | 70 | B |
| 1 | 9 | Math | Q2 | 52 | C |
| 1 | 9 | Science | Q1 | 69 | C |
| 1 | 9 | Science | Q2 | 80 | A |

I'm trying to do df.melt, but it's not working. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: check out ```pd.melt``` --> ```df.melt(id_vars=['ID','Grade','Course'],var_name='Semester',value_name='Grade')
```

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27764378/how-to-reverse-a-2-dimensional-table-dataframe-into-a-1-dimensional-list-using

Comment: @sophocles  Sorry, my question was a bit unclear. please see the edited one. How can we do it for multiple value_names?

Comment: Use [`pd.wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html#pandas-wide-to-long) (great function for simultaneous "melting" situations).

Answer (score 2):

Update:

```
df = pd.read_excel('Downloads/grades_mock+data.xlsx')

dfm = df.set_index(['ID', 'GRADE', 'COURSE'])\
        .rename(columns=lambda x: ' '.join(x.split(' ', 1)[::-1]))\
        .reset_index()

#Eliminating duplicates.
dfm = dfm.groupby(['ID', 'GRADE', 'COURSE', 'DISCIPLINE COURSE'], as_index=False).first()

df_out = pd.wide_to_long(dfm,
                         ['GRADE NUMERIC', 'GRADE LETTER'], 
                         ['ID', 'GRADE', 'COURSE', 'DISCIPLINE COURSE'],
                         'Semester', sep=' ', suffix='.*')\
           .reset_index()

print(df_out)
```

---

Try this, using `pd.wide_to_long`, with some column renaming to make it easier:

```
df = pd.read_clipboard()


dfm = df.set_index(['ID', 'Grade', 'Course'])\
        .rename(columns=lambda x: ' '.join(x.split(' ')[::-1]))\
        .reset_index()

df_out = pd.wide_to_long(dfm,
                         ['Number', 'Letter'], 
                         ['ID', 'Grade', 'Course'],
                         'Semester', sep=' ', suffix='.*')\
           .reset_index()

print(df_out)
```

Output:

```
   ID  Grade   Course Semester  Number Letter
0   1      9  English       Q1      73      B
1   1      9  English       Q2      69      C
2   1      9     Math       Q1      70      B
3   1      9     Math       Q2      52      C
4   1      9  Science       Q1      69      C
5   1      9  Science       Q2      80      A
```

Comment: It gives the following error:ValueError: the id variables need to uniquely identify each row

Comment: That means that you can have on one row with ID, Grade and Course.  Do you have some duplicates in your data for ID, Grade and Course?

Comment: If so, you can aggregate them, use first or last record, or pick another column that makes it unique per row.

Comment: There is no other column in the dataset that can make the combination unique. What do you mean by aggregating the columns? @Scott Boston

Comment: Tried to create a unique id column and used the same code. That didn't work as well

Comment: Is there a place you can share the data?   Or can you create mock data that duplicates your error?

Comment: I have messaged you on linkedin. thank you @Scott Boston

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much. Unfortunately, Stackoverflow is not giving me permission to upvote your solution due to my account status